# Eloquent BelongsToMany Relationship searches for is null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 tables `artist`, `catalog` & `cat_artist` (pivot table). When retrieving a row from my catalog table I want to get all the associated artists with it. I could just do this with raw sql but since using laravel it feels wrong because it has many of the functions to do this already. So I have a the function in my product model (product modal references the catalog table) to create the join

```
public function artists()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Artist', 'cat_artist', 'LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID', 'LOOK_UP_TO_ARTIST_ID');
    }
```

I then call this  before I return my view which gives me the the row from my catalog table

```
$product = Product::find($id);
```

Now I want to get all the artists that may belong to this product aswell so I call the following

```
$artists = $product->artists()->get();
```

This returns an emtpy result set

Here is the query log from the above

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["query"]=> string(60) "select * from `catelogue` where `catelogue`.`id` = ? limit 1" 
        ["bindings"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> int(96033) 
        } 
        ["time"]=> float(0.91) 
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        ["query"]=> string(289) "select `artist`.*, `cat_artist`.`LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID` as `pivot_LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID`, `cat_artist`.`LOOK_UP_TO_ARTIST_ID` as `pivot_LOOK_UP_TO_ARTIST_ID` from `artist` inner join `cat_artist` on `artist`.`id` = `cat_artist`.`LOOK_UP_TO_ARTIST_ID` where `cat_artist`.`LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID` is null" 
        ["bindings"]=> array(0) { } 
        ["time"]=> float(0.37) } }
```

This is all happening before I return the view and pass the data to the view

Everything else in the query is right apart from this where it's looking for `null`

```
where `cat_artist`.`LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID` is null
```

It should be this

```
where `cat_artist`.`LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID` = ?
```

Please help. I can't figure out where I have gone wrong

---

**EDIT**

Here are my DB tables - watered down as showing all cols would be a waste

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artist` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ARTIST` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ARTIST` (`ARTIST`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  ;

CREATE TABLE `catelogue` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CAT_NO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TITLE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BARCODE` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `BARCODE` (`BARCODE`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CAT_NO` (`CAT_NO`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `cat_artist` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LOOK_UP_TO_ARTIST_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID`,`LOOK_UP_TO_ARTIST_ID`),
  KEY `LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID` (`LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID`),
  KEY `LOOK_UP_TO_ARTIST_ID` (`LOOK_UP_TO_ARTIST_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Hopefully an answer can be found as to why it is putting `is null` in the where statement rather than the `product ID`

Also I have tested the resulting raw SQl by replacing `is null` with a `product id` and it does work in phpMyAdmin so the SQL been generated is correct up to the `is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of digging I found that I was using the wrong `var` to set the `$primaryKey`. I was using `$primary_id`. How or where I picked this up I don't know but it seems to be the root cause because I wasn't changing the primaryKey var but rather declaring a new one - **Stupid user error**

---

To Any one else finding this - double check your code.

Make sure you are assigning the **correct** variable.

Wrapping a `pre` tag around my `var_dump` helps to read a large obeject/array and helped me to find the issue

Answer (score 1):

This may sounds stupid, but I think it's beacuse your field names are in uppercase letters. so laravel cannot find the id column in attributes list in Project model. so it assumes you are search for null ids. 
So at least rename `ID` columns to `id`(lowercase).

Comment: I'm Flawed. I created a test db, changed the column to lower case and it worked! This is great that it works but it now poses rather a larger issue because I can't just go and change all my col's to lower case. Is there not a way to tell laravel/eloquent not to change columns names to lower case , and use the name as formatted? PS-  This seems like a really stupid bug as I'm explicating setting the primary key in the modal as `ID`

Comment: You don't have to change all the columns to lowercase. changing `id` column is enough. If you really needs to use your new db try to use mutators for model.

Comment: I thought mututors were correct but I was wrong. Mutators change the value, not the key. After much more digging I have found the correct answer